# How to map a value to another in Django Rest

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

The class_name is a numeric field corresponding to the player's character class.
I want to map those values to the character class name and display it in the serializer.

```
class Character(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=10)
   level = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
   class_name= models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
   pk_count = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
   resets = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

class CharacterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Character
        fields = ('name', 'level', 'class_name', 'pk_count', 'resets')
```

Current Output

```
{
  "name": "Player1",
  "level": 250,
  "class_name": 1,
  "pk_count": 200,
  "resets": 27
}
```

Desired Output

```
{
  "name": "Player1",
  "level": 250,
  "class_name": "Warrior",
  "pk_count": 200,
  "resets": 27
}
```

Is it possible to map this values?
Something like that `{ 1 : "Warrior" }`

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your class:

```
class Character(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=10)
    level = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    class_name= models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    pk_count = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    resets = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    #add a dict for your values
    values = {'1':'Warrior','2':'Whatever'}

    @property
    def class_name_value(self):
          return values[self.class_name] if values[self.class_name] else 'default'
```

And then your serializer:

```
class CharacterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Character
        fields = ('name', 'level', 'class_name_value', 'pk_count', 'resets')
```

Answer (score 1):

dmitryro's answer is a good way to easily get access to those mapped values anywhere in the site.  Another way to map a value to the field name, only within the serializer in question, would be to use a `SerializerMethodField`

```
class CharacterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = models.Character
        fields = ('name', 'level', 'class_name', 'pk_count', 'resets')

    def get_class_name(self, obj):
        try:
            return obj.values[str(obj.class_name)]
        except KeyError:
            return 'default'
```